# How should I change the data source depending on the link?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am creating a web solution that should run on two different web addresses. Depending on what link loads the site (ex www.tes1.com or www.test2.com) I want the website t use a different database.

I am checking for where the request comes from in the site master and I was planning to change the dbl file that all the web pages should use to another one. How can I do this? Is t even possible?

Comment: My question is even if that is possible what will be the pros and cons?Regarding performance and readibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its posible, you need to create a HTTP module where you check the context.Request.Url.ToString(). (its the current url for the website). Then you create a class with a static property called 'CurrentConnectionString'. You set the CurrentConnectionString in the HTTP module based an the url, then, for each connection to the database you use the CurrentConnectionString property.